# Looping through an array with jQuery's each causes an undefined value at the start when making string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, undefined

I have an array of values and I am making one long string out of them; to do this I am using jQuery's `each()` method, but when I `console.log()` the final value it has an `undefined` value appended at the start.

I did a `console.log()` for each value in the array and there is no undefined values present.

**CodePen:** http://codepen.io/gutterboy/pen/wGdqKo

**Code:**

```
var foo, options = [];

var defaults = [
    'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', '|',
    'five', 'six', 'seven', '|',
];

function bar () {
    $.each(defaults, function (index, value) {
        if ($.inArray(value, options) === -1) {
            if (value == '|') {
                foo += value;
            } else {
                foo += (index == 0) ? value : ',' + value;
            }
        }
    });
    console.log(foo);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    bar();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not initialize `foo`. Its initial value is therefore `undefined`. The `+=` operator appends a string to the current value, so you end up with `undefined` at the beginning of the whole final result.

Answer (score 1):

The code in codepen does not initialize foo.  Your code above initializes foo as an array. try:

```
var foo='';
```